# How do you call the grandchildren of a step-grandparent?

Tags: terminology, kinship-terms

My grandfather recently got remarried to a woman who herself has children and grandchildren.

My question is: what is the correct term to describe my relatedness to these people?

"Step-aunt" or "step-uncle" seemed odd to me, as it's usual to have "normal" prefix-less aunts and uncles related through marriage (rather than by blood). I've heard "step-cousin" used when uncles or aunts remarry, but I'm not sure if the term still applies in this case.

Comment: *"Step-aunt"* or *"step-uncle"* seemed odd to me, as it's usual to have "normal" prefix-less aunts and uncles related through marriage (rather than by blood). I've heard *"step-cousin"* used when uncles or aunts remarry, but I'm not sure if the term still applies in this case.

Answer (score 2):

There isn’t a specific term for that, although I think step-cousin would be close enough. Even a native English speaker would have trouble with that one! 
“My cousin is coming to dinner... well, he’s not really my cousin, he’s...um... ok, my step-grandfather got remarried, and this is his new wife’s... it’s complicated. Nevermind. My cousin is coming to dinner.”

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so, my mom's biological dad, my grandfather, died when my mom was 8 or so and my mom's mom, my grandmother, got remarried. This would make my grandmother's new husband my step-grandfather.
My step-grandfather has kids. They would be my mom's step-siblings, my step-aunt and step-uncle.
My step-aunt has a kid. And so did my step-uncle. These children would be my step-first-cousins.
Hope that helps :)

Answer (score -2):

Lets say your grandfather marries two wives. His first wife bears him one daughter and lets say they get divorced. Then when your grandfather marries a second wife (your stepmother) and your stepmother has a kid, lets say she also bears a daughter. These two daughters are known as half-sisters and their children are known as half-cousins (to each other). So the answer to your question is half-first cousin.

Comment: Welcome and thank for your contribution. However, the scenario in your answer is fundamentally different from the one described in the question. Which means that your concluded answer is likely also incorrect.